# Transformation to complex spherical basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, change-of-basis

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis) Wikipedia page about the complex spherical basis, it is stated that the spherical basis vectors are written in terms of the Cartesian basis vectors the following way:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e_{+} \\
e_{-} \\
e_{0}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e_{x} \\
e_{y} \\
e_{z}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\textbf{U}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
e_{x} \\
e_{y} \\
e_{z}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

However, the *"components"* of a vector transform by:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
A_{+} \\
A_{-} \\
A_{0}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & +\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & +\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
A_{x} \\
A_{y} \\
A_{z}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\textbf{U*}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
A_{x} \\
A_{y} \\
A_{z}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I understand that this is what you get by substituting the components of the vectors in the basis definition but, is there a better way to explain why the transformation matrix is conjugated when I go from transforming the basis vectors to transforming the *"components"* of a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_c$ denote the Cartesian basis as a column vector. Let $B_s$ be the spherical basis. Then we have $B_s=U B_c.$ If $v$ is a vector, let $v_c$ and $v_s$ be the coordinate representation in each basis. Then
$$
{B_c}^T v_c={B_s}^T v_s=(UB_c)^T v_s={B_c}^T U^T v_s.
$$
But because $B_c$ is a basis this gives $v_c=U^T v_s$ or $v_s=(U^T)^{-1} v_c.$ But because $U$ is unitary,
$$
(U^T)^{-1}=(U^{-1})^T=((U^*)^T)^T=U^*.
$$

Comment: Usually $U^*$ is the conjugate transpose, but I'm using $U^*$ as the conjugate to be consistent with Nomad's question.

Comment: To confirm that I understood: $ U $ unitary implies that $ U^{-1} = (U^T)^* $ and consequently $ (U^T)^{-1} = ((U^T)^T)^* = U^* $ ?

Comment: @Nomad. Basically. I updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Ok. Marked as answer, thank you for your time and effort!